# How can I pass request url value in logstash for elasticsearch output?

Tags: elasticsearch, url, logstash

I need a custom index pattern for elasticsearch output, which index name must contain the URL. How is it possible to pass url to index name?

Answer (score 0):

you cant according to their site:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/608a61ab85e82f8f6e88002ba7d8458411e7da62/core/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/cluster/metadata/MetaDataCreateIndexServiceTests.java#L188-L202

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/index-name-type-name-and-field-name-rules/133039

Maybe you can try using alias? (using a mapping between an url alias and a index).

Comment: Is it possible to  filter the url and make a short alias with letter [az-A-z] only?

Comment: Ok i made some try. Alias seems to accept more character than index name. You still cant use / for example. So i thinck you could create a function to map url to an alias name, and maybe a second one to map index name to the alias if you want to create them dynamicly.